# Android font sizing - ensuring X chars fits into a textview

Tags: android, layout, fonts, size

Is there any way to ensure that I can fit X numbers of characters (fixed width font) into a text view?

No code as of yet as it's still in design - I already know how much space I want the textview to take up (using weights so the width will be relative to the system it's on and the orientation. So the question is really to do with dynamic sizing of the text, i.e. I want to ensure that I can fit up to 4 digits into a single box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
android:ems="4"
```

this means that the textView will be always the width of 4 letters 'M' (MMMM).

If you use

```
android:minEms="4"
```

then the textView width will be at least 4 letters 'M'

P.S: Sorry for my english...